# Preloader - how to turn it off when returning from the subpage to the main page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need your help with preloader. I have main site (index.html) and one subpage (subpage.html). The preloader works fine when visit site but, when I return from subpage to main page the preloader is loading again - here is issue, i don't know how to stop it. I want to the preloader loading only once during the first visit to the main (index) page. I've got two files: index.html and subpage.html. Preloader div (.box) is in index.html. Code:

```
<script>
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('.box').fadeOut('slow', function() {
            $(this).remove();
        });
    }, 3500);
</script>
```

Comment: Well then you need to store the fact that the user has seen it, and condition your code to run only if they haven't. Look into [Local Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage), if the user visits the site first time or day wise then the `localStorage` will be set visited, and you have to check if the user is already visited or not, if not then run the `setTimeout` code like,

```
if(localStorage.getItem('visited')!='1')
   setTimeout(function() {
        $('.box').fadeOut('slow', function() {
            $(this).remove();
            localStorage.setItem('visited','1');
        });
    }, 3500);
}
```

Comment: The code above doesn't work. Now, preloader working all the time:(

Comment: Make the value `1` as string and try. I have updated my answer

Comment: You have added the above code on your index.html page, right ? Please tell me how you have loaded your subpage in index.html page ?

Comment: Yes, I added the code in index.html file. In index.html a have button which has property: onclick="window.location.href='subpage.html'" .